# How to add wechat (weixin) link to navigation menu?

Tags: menus, links, customization

The profile link of WeChat (or Weixin) has the following format: `weixin://contacts/profile/username`

As you can see, it doesn't use `http://` and that seems to be the reason that it cannot be added to the WordPress navigation menu.

Well you can add it, but after saving the menu, the URL field is blank (again).

The strangest thing is that the navigation menu does not exclusively save http(s); I just tried to save a telephone number URL (`tel:00861012345678`) and that is actually saved.

Is there any way to get the WeChat link to properly show?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter `kses_allowed_protocols` (`wp-includes/functions.php wp_allowed_protocols`) to add your protocol:

```
add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols', function( $protocols ) {
    $protocols[] = 'weixin';
    return $protocols;
});
```

The default values are 'http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'mailto', 'news', 'irc', 'gopher', 'nntp', 'feed', 'telnet', 'mms', 'rtsp', 'svn', 'tel', 'fax', and 'xmpp'.

Comment: Looks like a great filter, but apart from the missing comma, it does not have the desired effect.

Comment: Found [another way](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/kses_allowed_protocols/), but again it simply does not work. The `print_r` does not show the added protocol. Did something change in WP 4.1 that this doesn't work anymore?

Comment: @Piet I have just tested my code. It works. I could add a custom link with exactly the sample URL you have given in your question, and it showed up in the frontend.

Comment: super strange, there is a conflict with a specific setup. I have tried it on another setup which is running the same theme and there it indeed works.